# Can I exclude a javascript file from being used on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

I am using jQuery Qtip 1 and Qtip 2 plugin scripts.   I have to have them both linked on my homepage, but of course it gives errors because I am linking to both of them on the Homepage.  Is there a way to exclude Qtip 1 from JUST one page, or simply tell the page to only use this particular javascript instead of the other; perhaps I have to use jQuery?

Also, 80% of my pages are using Qtip 1, and only the homepage is using Qtip 2.

I am using Template pages.

Comment: Why do you need to have both of them?

Comment: Because 80% of my pages use Qtip1.  I have used an inline linking to get the Qtip2 script, just on the homepage, as opposed to the Qtip1 being in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class name to the `<body>` element in each page, then write `if ($('body').hasClass('something'))`.

Comment: I am using Template pages (edited above), so body class would be same for every page =(

Comment: @Todd: Then you can use any other element.  You can also check whether a specific element exists at all.

Comment: Ok, I understand...I do have a way to distinguish the homepage from all other pages using jQuery.  But how would I be able to exclude the use of a javascript file via jQuery then?

Comment: You need to exclude the entire script file? If so, you can execute it inside the `if` block by calling `$.getScript`.

Comment: Ok so from my understanding my only option is to do the opposite, which is tell it to load a script if on a certain page, would this be the best option seeing I only need it to load on one page; my concern here is load time?

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference in load time.  However, note that the script will load asynchronously.